# Scala actors on android

Tags: android, scala

I tried using actors in a small scala (2.8) app on android (2.1) today and I keep getting a really weird error referencing sun.misc.Unsafe.throwException.

I'm thinking that maybe the dalvik VM doesn't include this so Actors basically can't be used on android but I hope I'm wrong.

Did anyone manage to get actors working on android?

Comment: related: [Is it OK to use `scala.actors.Actor` object in an Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16137585/1048572)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, as a matter of fact, they work for me on either Android 2.1 or 2.2.

It is only simple use to do some extremely simple processing after an UI event occurs (setting coordinates on a PicturePanel), but Actors did work without problems so far.

The way I build & deploy the application is SBT with android-plugin 0.4.2 by jberkel, the versions of Scala used has included all versions from 2.8.0RC3 to RC6.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Must just be me screwing something up then. I'll give it another go.

Answer (score 1):

I could make `actors` work using scala 2.9.1. I have used [scala-android-libs](https://github.com/scala-android-libs/scala-android-libs) to install scala in my device.

You can also check this [blogpost](http://jgoday.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/scala-android-and-actors/) by jgoday.