# Is it OK to use `scala.actors.Actor` object in an Android application?

Tags: android, scala, actor

I know that it works, just checked. I'm wondering about the system not being able to free memory or the  application "hanging" in the background or such things.

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import android.util.Log

object Player extends Actor {

  start

  def act {
    loop {
      react {
        case x => Log.v("actor", "received: " + x)
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Actors are so much more *graspable* than concurrency using regular threads. I guess `scala.actors` is build upon JVM threads, so maybe it's as legal as using normal threads in your app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using native scala actors, as they're deprecated. But you can run AKKA on Android. You can see this thread for more information and sample code: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/1W41nAONv90